# Attach jQuery event handler to popup window contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

**EDIT** - A short/brief description of the question.  Is it possible using jQuery and javascript to intercept popup windows (on open) and listen/detect for keyboard input into text boxes from the parent window.

I am working on a site that has recently switched to Single Sign On type authentication.  As a result, the user's session is no longer controlled by the application, but rather a central authorization server.

In order to prevent users from being booted without realizing their session is timing out, we created a simple timer.  After X minutes of no activity, a warning banner appears with a link to extend the session.

Here is the code snippet we use to listen for activity on a web page

```
function DetectChanges() {
    $('input[type=text], textarea').on('change keyup paste', function () {
        console.log('Input detected - Resetting ession timers');
        $('input[type=text], textarea').off('change keyup paste');
        ResetSessionExpirationInformation();
        setTimeout(DetectChanges, msToCheckInput);
    });
}
```

Basically the premise is, every so often, see if the user is hitting the keyboard.  If so, extend the session and stop listening for keyboard input for a little bit.

The problem I am running into is that I need to be able to tell if the user is hitting the keyboard in a child window (old schoool popup, not a dialog or modal).  Since this site uses tons of inline JS, I don't have an easy way to gain access to these new windows.  However, I did find that I can override the `window.open` function in order to track the windows.

```
    var openedWindows = [];
    window._open = window.open; // saving original function
    window.open = function (url, name, params) {
    var newWin = window._open(url, name, params);
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.onload = setTimeout(DetectChangesChild(newWin), msToCheckInput);
    ResetSessionExpirationInformation();
    openedWindows.push(newWin);
```

I am passing the reference to the window in the above DetectChangesChild method so I have a reference later on the code path.

```
function DetectChangesChild(childWindow) {
    childWindow.alert("Listening Child Window");
    $(childWindow).contents('input[type=text], textarea').on('change keyup paste', function () {
        alert('Stuff happened');
        console.log('Input detected - Resetting session timers');
        childWindow.$('input[type=text], textarea').off('change keyup paste');
        ResetSessionExpirationInformation();
        setTimeout(DetectChangesChild(childWindow), msToCheckInput);
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to listen on text input elements in a popup for changes so that I can reset the session expiration timers appropriately?

Note - I am aware of the cautionary statements against overriding native functions, but we are in no danger of colliding with another override of this function.